# Removing duplicates while keeping parallel lists in sync

Tags: java, vector

This problem drives me crazy.I have vectorA(float),vectorB(string1),vectorC(string2) which are parallel and i want to eliminate the duplicates in vectorA ,while i manage to retain the 
parallelity among the vectors.
Any ideas?

Comment: Is `vectorA` sorted, or what?  Are you trying to eliminate exact duplicates, or duplicates within some epsilon, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `set<float>` for items that you have seen, scan through `vectorA` recording duplicate indexes, then delete indexes that you marked as duplicates while going back starting at the end of the vectors.

```
Set<Float> seen = new HashSet<Float>();
List<Integer> del = new List<Integer>();
for (int i = 0 ; i != vectorA.size() ; i++) {
    if (seen.add(vectorA[i])) {
        del.add(i);
    }
}
for (int i = del.size()-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    vectorA.remove(del[i]);
    vectorB.remove(del[i]);
    vectorC.remove(del[i]);
}
```

Going back is important, because otherwise your indexes will get out of sync.

Comment: thnx it seems to have the correct logic ,but i cant find those methods in java(?!).
insert() ?
push_back()?

Comment: @user1296783 Oops, I wrote C++ code instead of Java :) It should work now.

Comment: do you mean del.elementAt(i)?

Comment: @user1296783 Assuming it's a Vector, I mean [`remove(index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#remove(int)).

Comment: this is the output
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5 >= 5
i think you are right and im missing something ..humm

Answer (score 2):

Here's a single-pass, in-place algorithm:

```
Set<Float> seen = new HashSet<Float>();
int uniques = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  if (seen.add(vectorA[i])) {
    vectorA[uniques] = vectorA[i];
    vectorB[uniques] = vectorB[i];
    vectorC[uniques] = vectorC[i];
    uniques++;
  }
}
```

and then after you're done, ignore all elements after position `uniques` (or copy them all into new arrays).

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that combines the three values and overrides `equals` and `hashCode`. Add these instances to a single list instead of three parallel lists. Once you're ready to remove duplicates (assuming you need to keep them around first and remove them at a later point), add them to a `LinkedHashSet` and back to an `ArrayList`. `LinkedHashSet` will maintain insertion order (if that's not important use a standard `HashSet`) while removing duplicates.

```
class Triple {
    float num;
    String a;
    String b;

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null || !(o instanceof Triple))
            return false;
        return num == ((Triple)o).num;  // strict equality
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return Float.floatToRawIntBits(num);
    }
}

List<Triple> removeDuplicates(List<Triple> items) {
    return new ArrayList<Triple>(new LinkedHashSet<Triple>(items));
}
```